# MSSQL - IF within a TRIGGER

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, triggers

we're just migrating from mariadb (galera) to MSSQL.
One of our applications has a very special behaviour - from time to time (I have not found a pattern, the vendor uses very fancy AI-related stuff which noone can debug :-/) it will block the monitor-user of our loadbalancers because of too many connects, so the loadbalancer is no longer able to get the health state, suspends all services on all servers and the whole service is going down.

So I wrote a trigger which enables this user after he will be disabled.
I've already thought about a constraint which prohibits this, but then the application goes nuts if it will disable the user.

Anyway - in mysql this works perfectly for us:

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TRIGGER f5mon_no_disable AFTER UPDATE ON dpa_web_user
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.user_id = '99999999' AND NEW.enabled = 0  THEN
            UPDATE dpa_web_user SET enabled = 1 WHERE user_id = '9999999';
        END IF;
    END$$

delimiter ;
```

I tried this in T-SQL (if it's important, it is MSSQL 2016)

```
CREATE TRIGGER f5mon_no_disable ON [dbo].[dpa_web_user]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF ( inserted.[user_id] = '9999999' AND inserted.[enabled] = 0 )
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dpa_web_user SET enabled = 1 WHERE user_id = '9999999';
    END
END
```

I think it's the if-statement which is totally wrong in more than one way - but I do not have an idea how the syntax is in t-sql.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: In T-SQL triggers run once per DML statement, not once per row. Also to reference a column inside a table (in this case the `inserted` pseudo table) you need a `FROM`.

Comment: So, if I understand you right - this will work?


`CREATE TRIGGER f5mon_no_disable ON [dbo].[dpa_web_user]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF ( SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM inserted WHERE user_id = '9999999' AND enabled = 0 ) > 0
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dpa_web_user SET enabled = 1 WHERE user_id = '9999999';
    END
END
`

Comment: No, please don't _count all the rows_ just to verify that the count is _not 0_. [This is wasteful](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/10/t-sql-queries/bad-habits-count-the-hard-way).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `IF EXISTS` but you can't reference column values in `inserted` without set-based access to `inserted`:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE [user_id] = '9999999' AND [enabled] = 0)
BEGIN
    UPDATE dpa_web_user SET enabled = 1 WHERE user_id = '9999999';
END
```

You may want to add `AND enabled <> 1` to prevent updating a row for no reason.

You can do this in a single statement though:

```
UPDATE u
  SET enabled = 1
  FROM dbo.dpa_web_user AS u
  INNER JOIN inserted AS i
  ON u.[user_id] = i.[user_id]
  WHERE u.[user_id] = '9999999'
    AND i.[user_id] = '9999999'
    AND u.enabled <> 1
    AND i.enabled = 0;
```

Comment: `ON u.[user_id] = i.[user_id] WHERE u.[user_id] = '9999999' AND i.[user_id] = '9999999'` seems to have a bit of redundancy.

Comment: @HABO it does, but I've learned over the years that the more truths you tell SQL Server, the better opportunity it has to build the best plan. (For example, it might otherwise choose operators based on the wrong order of filtering if you've only put that predicate on one of the tables. It doesn't hurt to be more explicit.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand did I read that referred to as a "faux predicate" on your blog, or was that another SQL superstar?

Comment: @paneerakbari Was not me, but quite a similar concept expressed here for PostgreSQL might be what you are remembering: https://hakibenita.com/sql-dos-and-donts#add-faux-predicates